# Spark - Is scala really need to be installed to run "scala shell"

Tags: apache-spark

Small question . Is it really needed for "scala runtime " ( scala SDK ) to present or need to be installed for running spark shell or spark programs in "local mode"

JVM is already present.

Please share your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install the spark to the local, you can find the jars. And you can simply run the spark-shell without scala sdk.

[image]

Comment: awesome, BTW, what is with scala 2.11 Vs 2.12 . I see  different spark versions for each corresponding scala . What are so significant in them to have the specific spark version

Comment: Spark 2+ until 2.4.0 uses the scala 2.11 and after that uses the scala 2.12. The spark support and fixed the selected scala versions for the developing purpose AFAIK.

Comment: does it got anything to do with binary compatibility ?

Comment: 2.10 is deprecated with Spark 2.3.0 and 2.11 with 3.0.0, 2.12 is the live version. When you compile with the different versions of scala, it will be ok when the lower version is used before the deprecation but after that, the spark will cause some serious error in the job.

Answer (score 1):

Be default, Spark has Scala, Python Runtime. Scala would run on JVM. So you no need to create a separate runtime.